# Java code generation skips the property with type 'Class'

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen

I have a Serializable Java class with three properties of type String, List and Class. The generated Java code omits the property with type 'Class'.

I used `Swagger-codegen` version 2.2.2 and Eclipse maven plugin `Swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` version : 2.2.2

**Steps to reproduce**

Add Class as property in any of the Java serialization Object used in REST service

Generate Java client code using Maven plugin for swagger codegen

Please help me to understand why the property with type 'class' gets skipped in code generation?

**Original Class:**

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = MyDeserializer.class)
public class MyData<T> {

    private Class<?> type;
    private String dataName;
    private List<?> data;
```

**Swagger Generated Class**

```
******
}
/*
 * 
 * 
 *
 * NOTE: This class is auto generated by the swagger code generator program.
 * https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen.git
 * Do not edit the class manually.
 */


package io.swagger.client.model;

import java.util.Objects;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * MyDataobject
 */
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.languages.JavaClientCodegen", date = "2018-05-28T16:06:37.047+05:30")
public class MyDataobject {
  @SerializedName("data")
  private List<Object> data = new ArrayList<Object>();

  @SerializedName("dataName")
  private String dataName = null;

  public MyDataobject data(List<Object> data) {
    this.data = data;
    return this;
  }

  public MyDataobject addDataItem(Object dataItem) {
    this.data.add(dataItem);
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * Get data
   * @return data
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(example = "null", value = "")
  public List<Object> getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public void setData(List<Object> data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public MyDataobject dataName(String dataName) {
    this.dataName = dataName;
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * Get dataName
   * @return dataName
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(example = "null", value = "")
  public String getDataName() {
    return dataName;
  }

  public void setDataName(String dataName) {
    this.dataName = dataName;
  }


  @Override
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    MyDataobject myDataobject = (MyDataobject) o;
    return Objects.equals(this.data, myDataobject.data) &&
        Objects.equals(this.dataName, myDataobject.dataName);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(data, dataName);
  }


  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("class MyDataobject {\n");

    sb.append("    data: ").append(toIndentedString(data)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    dataName: ").append(toIndentedString(dataName)).append("\n");
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
  }

  /**
   * Convert the given object to string with each line indented by 4 spaces
   * (except the first line).
   */
  private String toIndentedString(java.lang.Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
      return "null";
    }
    return o.toString().replace("\n", "\n    ");
  }

}
<build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                <configuration> <mainClass>MyMainClass</mainClass> 
                </configuration> </plugin> -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.swagger.codegen}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>swagger.json</inputSpec>
                            <language>java</language>
                            <configOptions>
                                <sourceFolder>src/main/java</sourceFolder>
                            </configOptions>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <!-- the following is only necessary if you are using eclipse and m2e -->
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[${version.swagger.codegen},)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>generate</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Please add sample Java code, maven plugin config, etc., as well as the expected and actual results directly to your question. This will make it easier for others to understand what the issue is.

Comment: please add swagger file and a part of genereted code?

Comment: Added The details. Thank you!

Comment: I would bet the problem is that class Class is not serializable, so swagger couldn't write it for you...

Comment: @moilejter I have changed the field from Class<?> to Class<? extends Serailizable> But did not help. I think the problem is the Class Type iself

Comment: Binoj - I think you're right - and there's no way to make class Class serializable...  You would have to see if swagger has some transformer that can turn the non-serializable Class instance into its String name on serializaing, then use that string name to de-serialize it back into a class instance on read (if the class is available).
In a different context, I once got around this by storing in the instance both class instance (marked as a transient field) and class name (fully qualified, as a String) - and a getter for the class property that used the class name to instantiate the class...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried options given for Overriding the property types. Did not help. Ideally this problem should not come as generated JSON doesnt require Class<?> serialization. My deserializer converts the String value to JSON. I have no requirement for generate JSON response. So previously I have not added Serializer. Now I have added Serializer which converts Class to Json String. But Still Swagger Code Gen did not generate Type property in API Object.

Comment: I have tried ApiModelProperty (required =true, value="${type.name}") but not successful.  Noticed ApiModelProperty is not at all working for this Class<?> but its working for all other fields for any configurations (like hidden , value, name etc)